# How to set background color of Android ListView entries/items?

Tags: android-layout, android-styles

I have a ListView with entries that have a lighter background color than the application's layout, and I don't know why.This is a snapshot with red arrows indicating the difference in color: [Main_Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ7Wl.jpg)

I have no idea where to start on this.

This is the manifest.xml file that takes up the theme, AppTheme:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gtfp.workingmemory"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="19"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <!-- Start an Alarm When the Device Boots if past due -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".appController"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".editToDoItem"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".ToDoAlarm">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
                android:name=".AlarmActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".SettingsActivity"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

That theme in fact is Theme.Holo in the resources file:

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
    -->
<!--    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">  -->

    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo">

        <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

This is the main layout for the application you'll see the ListView here:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}">

    <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvToDos"
            android:layout_width="206dp"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:smoothScrollbar="false"
            android:layout_above="@+id/itemEntryView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            >
    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/itemEntryView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewToDo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:onClick="editToDoItem"
                android:text="@string/new_item"
                android:textSize="@dimen/smallTextSize"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Each row in the ListView is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:gravity="center"
 android:id="@+id/container"
 android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
        >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/priorityImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:src="@drawable/low"
            />

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/itemText"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:gravity="center_vertical"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textStyle="bold"
     />

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/itemDueDate"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
       android:scaleType="center"
       android:textSize="12sp"
       android:focusable="false"
       android:textStyle="bold"
       android:gravity="center"
       />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.
In the getView, I'm producing 'rounded corners' for every item in the ListView by setting their resource background to a customized drawable:

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
:
:
:
:
            convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rounded_corner);
   }
```

Well, in the drawable, I found there was a solid colour being drawn in there. I commented it out, and now I get what I want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!--    <solid android:color="#433E41"/>  -->

    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

    <padding android:left="3dp" android:top="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:bottom="3dp" />

    <stroke android:width="3dp" android:color="#E6E6E6"/>
</shape>`enter code here`
```

I just happened upon this while investigating another matter (I hate porgramming). Appreciate your efforts regardless.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to change the background color of your list view if this is the case then you can easily do this in your custom listview base adapter you can do it in your base adapter's getview Method. 
here is the sample code

```
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = new TextView(ListHighlightTestActivity.this);
        convertView.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
        //here I am changing the color of text in textview 
        ((TextView)convertView).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }

    convertView.setBackgroundColor((position == curSelected) ? 
        Color.argb(0x80, 0x20, 0xa0, 0x40) : Color.argb(0, 0, 0, 0));
    ((TextView)convertView).setText((String)getItem(position));

    return convertView;
}
```

or alternatively if you know the idea of using selector then you can easily achieve it through selector.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@color/BackgroundColor" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/transparent" />
</selector>
```

I am sure your problem would get solved in these two above mentioned solutions. Use any of them, which ever is easy for you.

Answer (score 0):

Set app color in list view

```
  <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvToDos"
        android:layout_width="206dp"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:smoothScrollbar="false"
        android:background="@color/app_color"
        android:layout_above="@+id/itemEntryView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        >
</ListView>
```